# スクレイピングした画像は表示できるか

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

PythonのBeautifulSoupを利用してスクレイピングをしていますが、

imgタグのsrcにあるURLを取得した場合、
ローカルに保存せずにその画像をどこかに表示することは可能でしょうか。

ご回答のほど、よろしくお願い致します。

===

OS: Mac
Python: 2.7.10
ライブラリ:
beautifulsoup4: 4.6.1
lxml: 4.2.5
requests: 2.21.0

===

Comment: 「どこかに表示」というのは表現として曖昧過ぎる気がします。

Comment: できればコンソール上に表示できれば一番良いのですが、不可能で他に方法があれば教えていただきたいです

Comment: 「コンソールに画像を表示」は特にスクレイピングとは関係ない、独立した質問ではないでしょうか。Google等で検索するだけでもいくつか方法がヒットするので、それらに目を通してもらった上で分からない事があれば個別の質問として投稿してみてください。

Comment: [前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51180/%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%92%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)に対する[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/51186/29826)で含めたのですが、お読みになられましたか？

Comment: @PicoSushi ありがとうございます！試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

取得した画像のURLが通常の手段で参照可能であるなら、自分でHTMLなどを生成すればローカルに保存せずに直接参照(=表示)できるでしょう。
ただしIMGタグで画像の参照先が相対パスであった場合には、適時`http`等から始まる絶対パスに置きかる必要があります。